# ASP.NET MVC 3 views, super classes don't work for subclasses?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-membership, covariance

I have the following classes -

```
public abstract class BusinessObject { }
public abstract class Form: BusinessObject { }
public abstract class BillableForm: Form { }
public class MembershipForm: BillableForm { }

public abstract class Dto<T>: where T: BusinessObject { }
public abstract class InboxDto<T>: Dto<T> where T: Form { }
public class MembershipFormDto: InboxDto<MembershipForm> { }
```

And I have the following views -

```
membershipform.cshtml:
@model AdminSite.Models.MembershipFormDto
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Inbox/Shared/_LayoutForm.cshtml"
}

_LayoutForm.cshtml:
@model InboxDto<Form>
```

When I land on the membershipform.cshtml page, I get the following exception stating:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AdminSite.Models.MembershipFormDto', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AdminSite.Infrastructure.Models.InboxDto`1[BusinessLogic.Inbox.Form]'.

From everything I can tell, `MembershipFormDto` IS-A `InboxDto` of type `MembershipForm`, where `MembershipForm` IS-A `Form`.  What gives?

Comment: Can you post the code for your action method?

Comment: The exception isn't coming from the action method.  The action method works fine when I switch `_LayoutForm.cshtml` to use `@model dynamic` but I'd rather have a strongly typed model.  This is an issue with the C# typing system possibly and some ignorance on my part.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an issue of covariance.

I added the following interface -

```
public interface IInboxDto<out T>
```

and modified the InboxDto class to implement that interface -

```
public abstract class InboxDto<T>: Dto<T>, IInboxDto<T> where T: Form { }
```

In short, covariance is going from a more defined type to a less defined type; specifically referencing a more defined object with a less defined reference.  The reason the compiler complains is it's preventing a scenario like this:

```
List<String> instanciatedList = new List<String>;
List<Object> referenceList = instanciatedList;
referenceList.add(DateTime);
```

The final line makes sense, a `DateTime` IS-A `Object`.  We've said `referenceList` is a `List` of `Object`.  However it's instanciated as a `List` of `String`.  A `List` of `Object` is more permissive than a `List` of `String`.  Suddenly our guarantees from `new List<String>` are being ignored.

However the out and in keywords for `Interface` definitions tells the compiler to relax, we know what we're doing and understand what we're getting ourselves into.

[More information.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/253417/Understanding-Covariance-and-Contravariance-in-Net)

Comment: 3 hours of wrestling with this problem until I finally ask on SO.  Then it takes me 20 minutes to find the answer myself.  Le sigh.

Comment: Well, typically the process of defining the problem makes us think about the problem more clearly, and often pushes us to recognize the problem.  It's a great question though, and while your solution works.. I would caution anyone that doesn't know exactly what they're doing to be careful.

Comment: Yes, any time one tells the compiler to back off, they're implicitly claiming they know what the dangers are.  Here be dragons :)